# PHP pass coma delimited string as multiple parameters to a function

Tags: php, php-5.6

I would like to call something like this:

```
<?php
   function returner($par1,$par2){
      var_dump($par1);
      var_dump($par2);
      return false;
   }

   $func_name = 'returner';
   $args = array('arg1','arg2');
   $func_name('"'.implode('","',$args).'"');
?>
```

But the problem is, that PHP sends that as single argument to `$func_name()`:

`$arg1` is `'"arg1","arg2"'`, `$arg2` is not defined.

How do I make it work properly (so params would be send separately) without modifying a `returner()` function?

Comment: @CBroe - And from somebody that proclaims themself as "Director of Technology Development" at that

Comment: Wow :-) So much hate... that question was asked by my friend from my account. I didn't have time to help him. But I like the `...$args` solution... so I changed his picked answer to the one with PHP 5.6+ solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using PHP 5.6, you can take advantage of the `splat` operator:

```
$func_name(...$args);
```

See https://eval.in/916622

Answer (score 1):

You use `call_ser_func_array`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php